# Remote admin for JMS

Tags: glassfish, jms

We are running Glassfish, and we are using QBroker to help with our JMS queue monitoring/debugging. This works well if the QBroker and Glassfish are on the same server.

We have a remote Glassfish server, and we are not able to connect to it in the same manner. The QBrowser fails to connect to the remote server with this error:

`Failed to connect to the broker using input information.
Please make sure the broker is running or host/port/user/password is correct.
[C4062]: Cannot perform operation, connection is closed.`

I have port 7676 open on the remote server (I've verified it with telnet).

I can't find anything in the remote Glassfish logs that suggests what the problem is.

Do I need to configure something to allow a remote connection? Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: is there solution for your problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately we didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately fixed my problem with QBrowser.

The problem was with firewall.

In my case it was not sufficient to open port 7676. When I tried to run QBrowser with logs in console(changed javaw to java in bat file), browser throws exception

```
Error occurred on connection creation [HOST:43890]. - cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Maybe it is dynamic port. I opened all ports on server for my IP address. After this, QBrowser connects without any problem. Maybe you had same problem.